# Randomly arising "Permission denied" in php mkdir (windows)

Tags: php, mkdir, permission-denied

I am wrestling with a problem. I stripped the example to this script that can be run as stand-alone application:

```
<?php
if(file_exists("x")){
    print "<div>Deleting dir</dir>";
    rmdir("x");
} else {
    print "<div>Not exists</dir>";
}
clearstatcache();
mkdir("x");
```

If I call it repeatedly (F5 in browser) then sometimes this error occurs:

```
Deleting dir
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in F:\EclipseWorkspaces\Ramses\www\deploy\stripped_example.php on line 9
```

10-20 times it works OK and next time this error occurs. I googled more users has this problem but without solution.
https://github.com/getgrav/grav/issues/467
My example creates the directory in cwd, where anybody has full control. In addition the mkdir $mode parameter is ignored in windows. After the error the "x" directory truly not exists and in next attempt (F5) it is always created without error. I hopped later added "clearstatcache()" will help but nope.

In my full application I am using full file path. The deleted directory is not empty and I must clean it first. After successfull deleting the error occurs almost always.

My system is Windows 7, PHP 7.0.5, Apache 2.4

Comment: Why would you hammer your refresh button with this code? You are probably creating a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), i.e. sometimes when `mkdir` gets called the directory already exists due to another instance of the same script running concurrently.

Comment: I dont press F5 permanently. After the page appears complete without error, I press F5 for next attempt to prove random character of this error.

Comment: Premature joy from installing newest version PHP 7.0.10, it didnt help but the occurrence in application decreased from 100% to about 30%.

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't let you delete things if another process is accessing them.

Check if your antivirus or some other process is opening the folder.

You can check this in resource monitor, from task manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code with additional check on existing:

```
<?php
if(is_dir("x")){
    print "<div>Deleting dir</dir>";
    rmdir("x");
} else {
    print "<div>Not exists</dir>";
}
clearstatcache();
if (!is_dir("x")) {
   mkdir("x");
}
```

Comment: The "x" directory truly not exists, so the is_dir() returns always false. This is the mostly stripped example. In the application I am testing the file type for directory.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with Windows 10, Xampp and PHP 7. Problem was Kaspersky Internet Security, scanning and blocking the directory. Disabling KIS `mkdir` always works for me. Instead of directly recreating you can try `rename`, if disabling security software is not an option for you.

```
$time = time();
mkdir($path . $time);
rename($path . $time, $path);
```

Answer (score 0):

juste delete espace name folder with Function Trim in php